# Not able to access admin on Strapi

Tags: node.js, database, server, strapi, replit

STrapi page is working correctly for me on local host but when i hosted it on replit it gives these errors

```
main.9c01de7f.js:2981 Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/project-type' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:".

(anonymous) @ main.9c01de7f.js:2981
main.9c01de7f.js:171 oe
(anonymous) @ main.9c01de7f.js:171
main.9c01de7f.js:3929 Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/init' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:". 

The code can be seem here https://replit.com/@MAAZ-GAMERGAMER/SelfreliantEdibleDatalog?v=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Strapi enforces [CSP](https://content-security-policy.com/connect-src/) in the backend.

in your `my-project`
add the following in /config/middlewares.js

```
{
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'http:', 'https:'],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

The file would look like this:

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
{
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'http:', 'https:'],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

Comment: In which file please tell by seeing the code https://github.com/Maaz4f/Maaz-Store/tree/main/strapi-simple-one-client

Comment: I changed it but i am still recieving the error on this page https://selfreliantedibledatalog.maaz-gamergamer.repl.co/admin

Comment: git hub link isnt owrking

Comment: Hey @Maaz Saeed, let me know if this does not solve your issue. If it does, pls accept the answer