# Strapi can't access admin page

Tags: node.js, database, server, strapi, replit

STrapi page is working correctly for me on local host but when i hosted it on replit it gives these errors

main.9c01de7f.js:2981 Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/project-type' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:". (anonymous) @ main.9c01de7f.js:2981 main.9c01de7f.js:171 oe (anonymous) @ main.9c01de7f.js:171 main.9c01de7f.js:3929 Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/init' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:". The code can be seem here https://replit.com/@MAAZ-GAMERGAMER/SelfreliantEdibleDatalog?v=1

please tell by seeing the code https://github.com/Maaz4f/Maaz-Store/tree/main/strapi-simple-one-client

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to access admin on Strapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599863/not-able-to-access-admin-on-strapi)