# Not able to access admin on strapi [kube deployment]

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, strapi

I am getting the below error when trying to access admin page:
Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/admin/project-type' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https:".

This was also asked in the below link:
[Not able to access admin on Strapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75599863/not-able-to-access-admin-on-strapi)

I added the changes to the file as suggested, however they dont seem to have taken effect, as I am still getting the error.

Is there a command I should run after adding the changes?

I added the below changes in bold to the file config/middlewares.js

```
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'http:', 'https:'],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

The file now looks like this:

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'http:', 'https:'],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
  ];
```